# ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure - What's causing this?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have Autonomous Database running in OCI.  I'm able to connect to it from Oracle SQL Developer using the downloaded 'Wallet ZIP' file on a Windows machine.  However, when I tried to connect to it via sqlplus on the same Windows machine, I keep getting this error:

ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

I had all the files from the 'wallet.zip' copied to my ..\network\admin directory (Oracle client dir).
From my research, it only requires 'sqlnet.ora' and 'tnsnames.ora' files.  But I decided to put all the files there anyway.

Anyone able to offer some help?

Thanks